# Asteroids style motion, direction of travel does not line up with direction of vector triangle

Tags: c

I am currently trying to recreate the classic game Asteroids.

As of this moment I have managed to create a vector triangle on my screen and I have been able to make this triangle rotate around an origin point. I am now currently trying to get the triangle to move in the same way that the ship in the original game moves, with that floaty/on ice kind of feel. My problem however is that the direction of the ship's travel when the up button is pressed is not in line with the triangle's direction. I.e. the triangle travels off at the wrong direction and looks daft.

I am pretty sure the physics for the motion of the triangle is fine, so I think the error might be with the definition of the triangle but I am not sure. My code is below:

```
//handles updating the game state, moving the objects, and handling collisions.

#include "gamestate.h"

struct gameState_t{
        int lives;
} game;

struct ship_t{
    int heading;
    int x, y;
    double vx, vy;
    int speed;
    bool isAcc; //isAccelerating
} ship;

void physics(void)
{
    moveShip();
}


void initGameState(void){

    ship.heading = 0;
    ship.x = 240;
    ship.y = 240;
    ship.vx = 0;
    ship.vy = 0;
    ship.speed = 0;
    ship.isAcc = false; //acceleration

}




//getters

int getShipX(void){
    return ship.x;
}

int getShipY(void){
    return ship.y;
}

int getShipHeading(void){
    return ship.heading;
}

int getShipSpeed(void)
{
    return ship.speed;
}

bool getShipAcc(void)
{
    return ship.isAcc;
}

double getShipVx(void)
{
    return ship.vx;
}

double getShipVy(void)
{
    return ship.vy;
}


void moveShip(void)
{
        ship.x += (ship.vx / 10);
        ship.y += (ship.vy / 10);
}











void incHeading(void)
{

    ship.heading++;

    if(ship.heading < 0)
    {
        ship.heading = 360;
    }

    if(ship.heading > 360)
    {
        ship.heading = 0;
    }
}

void decHeading(void)
{
    //ship.heading = ship.heading - 6;
    ship.heading--;

    if(ship.heading < 0)
    {
        ship.heading = 360;
    }

    if(ship.heading > 360)
    {
        ship.heading = 0;
    }
}

void accelerate(void)
{
    float shipHeadingRads = (ship.heading * (PI / 180));
    //float shipHeadingRads = ship.heading;

    ship.vy += sin(shipHeadingRads) * acceleration;
    ship.vx += cos(shipHeadingRads) * acceleration;

}
```

This next part is the code that is used to draw the triangle on the screen, however this is used in another module.

```
void drawShipActive(void)
{
    int shipX = getShipX();
    int shipY = getShipY();
    int shipHeading = getShipHeading();

    float shipHeadingRads = (shipHeading * (PI / 180));

    int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
    int x1r, y1r, x2r, y2r, x3r, y3r;

    /*
    x1 = shipX;
    y1 = shipY - 20;
    x2 = shipX - 10;
    y2 = shipY + 10;
    x3 = shipX + 10;
    y3 = shipY + 10;
    */

    x1 = shipX;
    y1 = shipY + 20;
    x2 = shipX - 10;
    y2 = shipY - 10;
    x3 = shipX + 10;
    y3 = shipY - 10;

    x1r = ((x1 - shipX) * cos(shipHeadingRads)) - ((shipY - y1) * -(sin(shipHeadingRads))) + shipX;
    y1r = ((shipY - y1) * cos(shipHeadingRads)) - ((x1 - shipX) * sin(shipHeadingRads)) + shipY;
    x2r = ((x2 - shipX) * cos(shipHeadingRads)) - ((shipY - y2) * -(sin(shipHeadingRads))) + shipX;
    y2r = ((shipY - y2) * cos(shipHeadingRads)) - ((x2 - shipX) * sin(shipHeadingRads)) + shipY;
    x3r = ((x3 - shipX) * cos(shipHeadingRads)) - ((shipY - y3) * -(sin(shipHeadingRads))) + shipX;
    y3r = ((shipY - y3) * cos(shipHeadingRads)) - ((x3 - shipX) * sin(shipHeadingRads)) + shipY;

    screen->drawTriangle(x1r, y1r, x2r, y2r, x3r, y3r, GREEN);
}
```

I am assuming this is a relatively minor problem but I'm not sure where the problem lies exactly.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `ship.vy += sin(shipHeadingRads) * acceleration;` ... and it what direction is the acceleration?

Comment: The acceleration is just a fixed constant of 0.3, is this wrong?

Comment: You need to break acceleration into it's `x, y, (and z in 3D)` components. You just can't add a constant `0.3` -- it is a **vector** not a **scalar**.

Answer (score 0):

When shipHeadingRads is 0, you will be accelerated in the positive X direction (because cos(0) is 1 and sin(0) is 0).

```
ship.vy += sin(shipHeadingRads) * acceleration;
ship.vx += cos(shipHeadingRads) * acceleration;
```

However, the triangle's "point" will be in the positive Y direction because that's the shape you're drawing:

```
x1 = shipX;
y1 = shipY + 20;
x2 = shipX - 10;
y2 = shipY - 10;
x3 = shipX + 10;
y3 = shipY - 10;
```

If you draw the points (0,20), (-10,-10) and (10,-10) on paper you'll see the pointy side is in the positive Y direction.

You need to change either one of these things.

Comment: I have actually tried changing the initial direction of the triangle's point. When I changed it so that the direction of the triangle aligned in the positive X direction the triangle would travel in the correct direction as long as the heading remained at 0. As soon as I adjusted the heading direction the direction and orientation became misaligned again.

Comment: @Ajek Perhaps you also have the display rotating in the opposite direction of the way the acceleration rotates - try reversing one of them.

Comment: Nope, this still isn't working. I now have the triangle's point drawing in the positive X direction with a starting heading of 90 which makes the triangle's point rotate to the positive Y direction. When I press the up button the triangle then begins to move in the negative X direction.